# Cast one type to another

Tags: c#, entity-framework, casting

```
class childType: MainType{}

MainType mObj = GetData();

childType cObj = (childType)mObj;
```

How can I cast above

```
childType cObj = (childType)mObj;
```

I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.MainType_F04DC499C53D433B05ABEDEE7191583DB11728F68B18671613EF0E5AC158DD0D' to type 'ChildType'.

Comment: What type does `GetData();` return?  Is it really a `childType`?

Comment: If your `GetData()` method returns an instance of `MainType` then you can't legitimately cast it to `childType`.  If `GetData()` returns a `childType` object or something derived from that, then the cast will work.  This is by design.  You could try `childType cObj = mObj as childType;` which will result in null if the type isn't compatible.

Comment: @DStanley GetData() returns MainType

Comment: Remember what a cast means. A cast means "I promise you that this conversion is valid; throw an exception if I'm wrong."  You are wrong; the conversion is not valid, and so an exception is being thrown. If that's not the behaviour that you want then either (1) make a cast that *is* a valid conversion or (2) use the `is` operator instead of a cast and deal with the resulting null.

Comment: @EricLippert Did you mean 'as' rather than 'is'?

Comment: @DanielKelley: I am typing faster than I am thinking apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of EF5 dynamic proxies. Even if you want to cast

```
mObj = (MainType)cObj;
```

like this, you wouldn't. Because dynaimc proxy creates runtime concrete types. So you can disable dynamic proxy or inject values explicitly. If you close dynamic proxy you cannot use Lazy Loading neither.

So my advice simply use [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/). It has extension methods for object. And you can write something like this :

```
//this is not dynamic proxy object.
childType cObj = new childType().InjectFrom(mObj) as childType;

//or

// but this comes from dynamic proxy.
childType cObj = DbSet<childType>.Create().InjectFrom(mObj) as childType;
```

And you will see all hundreds of properties are injected by your mObj properties.

Comment: Sounds promising, will try this and let you know

Comment: Excellent, this is what i wanted it is working. Hope moving further, I will not have any issues with ValuInjector. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You should have a constructor in your child type that takes an instance of the main type.

Then you can do:

```
childType cObj = new childType(mObj);
```

Given this constructor on childType:

```
public childType(MainType obj)
{
    //set child type properties here
}
```

Comment: Technically this is a copy, not a cast, but it may be what the OP needs.

Comment: @DStanley Subtly different, but 100% correct :). I suspect this is what OP needs too.

Comment: An explicit conversion operator is a similar alternative, but I think the OP is confused about when it is valid to *cast* instead of *convert*.

Comment: copy constructors are a good solution, but on large classes they get tedious to write. Check out [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) if you go the route suggested in this answer

Comment: @mattytommo MainType has about 200 properties and it is under development stage, there may be lot of changes coming for this MainType. So i wan to avoid explicit property setting.

Comment: @StevenMagana-Zook can you please throw some more light on Copy Constructor. in my case my I am not dealing with list but, one class with many properties

Comment: @HaBo a [Copy Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a constructor that takes as a parameter an instance of the same type and copies the property values from that instance to the its own properties (in essence making a copy of the passed in object). This is similar to what mattytommo is doing in this answer except the passed in instance is of a derived/sub type. When your class has a lot of properties, something like the AutoMapper I mentioned is convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The cast you're attempting isn't actually possible. If you had something like;

```
 MainObj myObj = new ChildObj();
 ChildObj cObj = (ChildObj)myObj;
```

it would work. You could also cast a child object to it's parent class (specific to general) but you can't go from general to specific because being a `MainObj` is not sufficient for being a `ChildObj` (being a `ChildObj` is sufficent for being a `MainObj`, it has everything `MainObj` has plus more).

You can either make a constructor for ChildObj that takes in a MainObj and returns a ChildObj with default values for it's other properties or just reconsider your design. You should be asking the question of "Why would I cast a parent into a child?"

The opposite makes sense because you may have 5 classes that inherit from a common base class and override methods within it. You want some other method to be able to accept all five and invoke their specific functionality. This is accomplished via inheritance or by implementing an interface. Going from the general to the specific however, doesn't make sense nearly as often.